# Parse JSON Array using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, json.net

I'm working on a project in which I want to **deserialize** a JSON Array. I have tried but didn't get how to parse it.

**JSON ARRAY:**

```
{"showAttendanceResult":[{"lec_no":"FA10-BCS-40","reg_no":"2","std_status":"A","std_username":"fahidnadeem"},{"lec_no":"FA10-BCS-4","reg_no":"2","std_status":"A","std_username":"muneebamjad"}]}
```

Here is the JSON which I get from the WebService:

**How I Tried:**

```
    string URL = "http://localhost:32319/ServiceEmployeeLogin.svc/getattendance";
    WebRequest wrGETURL;
    wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(URL + "/" + Server.UrlEncode("24-06-2014"));
    wrGETURL.Method = "POST";
    wrGETURL.ContentType = @"application/json; charset=utf-8";
    HttpWebResponse webresponse = wrGETURL.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    // read response stream from response object
    StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

    // read string from stream data
    strResult = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
    // close the stream object
    loResponseStream.Close();
    // close the response object
    webresponse.Close();

    RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(strResult);

    //what to do now?
    }
}

public class ShowAttendanceResult
{
    public string lec_no { get; set; }
    public string reg_no { get; set; }
    public string std_status { get; set; }
    public string std_username { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<ShowAttendanceResult> showAttendanceResult { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I want the values in string, im new and i dont know how to get these values from json array.

Comment: @DhavalPatel thanks for your response, but how can i get these values FA10-BCS-40, 2, A from `"lec_no":"FA10-BCS-40","reg_no":"2","std_status":"A"`

Comment: see my ans I have posted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(strResult);

foreach(var item in ro.showAttendanceResult)
{
    string _name= item.lec_no;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
foreach(var item in ro.showAttendanceResult)
{
    string lec_no = item.lec_no;
}
```